# Constructing a hexagonal shape from quads (Bolt)

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

I want to model a bolt with a hexagonal inset (allen/hex key). The issue is, that I have not achieved this yet.

I have attempted multiple things, but they resulted in n-gons/tris or are not subdividable.
I would like to avoid using tris, as I know it is possible to construct something like this from purely quads.

Any help appreciated. Best regards!

Here is what I want to achieve - Just with clean geometry. (Made using boolean)

[image: example]

Here is a demo file incoprorating vklidu's solution and my correction!

[Link to the demo file](https://blend-exchange.com/b/BdgPVmS1)

Comment: Can add pictures or references of the shape you are trying to create? It's hard to guess it from your current post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a 6 vertex cylinder, bevel its vertices:

[image]

Extrude outwards, then right click > *LoopTools > Circle*:

[image]

Fill the inner face:

[image]

Extude down the whole mesh:

[image]

Extrude down the inner face:

[image]

Bevel the edges:

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, shade smooth;

[image]

Comment: Hehe.. much neater than the previous version :)

Comment: yes, plus it's usable, lol... I think I've already answered this kind of question but I couldn't put my hand on it

Answer (score 7):

Probably you can save some time ... Blender contains **BoltFactory** addon with Allen bit type included ...

- select problematic part, *Delete Faces*

[image]

- select hexagon and in this case *Subdivide* by 5
- search for **Bridge Edge Loops** operator

[image]

- for the bottom hexagon you can use topo like this (if you need avoid tris or n-gons)

[image]

- for a bottom tris - *Delete Faces*

[image]

- and search for **Grid Fill** operator

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation! Unless I misunderstood, the topology in your third picture still creates n-gons at the side of the inset. It is however possible to turn all this into quads! I have attached a proof-of-concept to the original post.

Comment: On second image you can see Tris at hexagon bottom hole so I connected corners in a quad topo. Sides are squares.